# Mouse left click interlocked with a Fn key

Tags: mouse, mouse-click, function-keys

This suddenly happened, whenever I left click my mouse, the windows help center is opening (which I figured out, comes up if you press F1 key)

So looks like, my left mouse click has been mapped to F1 key (I think so, please correct me if I am wrong)

Is there a solution for this, i.e to let left click act only as left click and not as any other command? Please help.

Edit: I just restarted the computer. While booting, continuous beeping occurs 15-20 times and then it stops and then windows boots. Looks like some key is stuck (correct me if I am wrong here). Please let me know what to do here.

Comment: Honestly if you suspect the mouse or keyboard try using a different mouse or keyboard to diagnose the issue. If it happens no matter what then we know it's Windows.

Comment: Tried doing that. Looks like my F1 key is gone. >.<